# FFMPEG Inverts colors when converting tiff pictures to png

Tags: java, ffmpeg, png, tiff, converters

We need to convert thousands of tiff pictures to png. To accomplish that we are using FFMPEG. We've noticed recently that for very few of the converted files (in png), the colors are inverted: the input tiff file is all black and white (a technical drawing in black with a white background), and the output png file is white and black (the drawing becomes white and the background becomes black). Of course we don't want that, we need the colors to stay the same.

Here is the command we are using:

```
ffmpeg -y -v warning -i in_file.tif out_file.png
```

We've tested the 'negate' parameter on those files, and the pictures are correctly converted. But we can't apply this parameter to all of the input tiff files.
Here is the command with the negate parameter:

```
ffmpeg -y -v verbose -i input.tif -vf negate output.png
```

**The Code Java we're using :**

```
            String ffmpegPath="/Users/user11/ffmpeg//ffmpeg";
            List<String> commandArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
            commandArgs.add(ffmpegPath);
            //overwrite output file if it exists
            commandArgs.add("-y");      
            commandArgs.add("-v");
            commandArgs.add("verbose");
            //set input file 
            commandArgs.add("-i"); 
            commandArgs.add(picture.getAbsolutePath());
            commandArgs.add(dest.getAbsolutePath());
            
            String cmd = "";
            for(String cmdArg : commandArgs) {
                cmd += cmdArg + " ";
            }
```

**Logs for tif having the bug:**

```
31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: Executing : /Users/user11/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -y -v verbose -i /Users/user11/ffmpeg/input.tif /Users/user11/ffmpeg/output.png 
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: ffmpeg version 4.4-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: [tiff_pipe @ 0x7fa7f6008200] parser not found for codec tiff, packets or times may be invalid.
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:     Last message repeated 1 times
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: Input #0, tiff_pipe, from '/Users/user11/ffmpeg/input.tif':
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Stream #0:0: Video: tiff, 1 reference frame, monob, 2008x2481 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2008:2481], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: Stream mapping:
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (tiff (native) -> png (native))
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7fa7f4c08300] w:2008 h:2481 pixfmt:monob tb:1/25 fr:25/1 sar:1/1
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: Output #0, image2, to '/Users/user11/ffmpeg/output.png':
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Metadata:
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:     encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Stream #0:0: Video: png, 1 reference frame, monob(progressive), 2008x2481 (0x0) [SAR 1:1 DAR 2008:2481], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:     Metadata:
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:       encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 png
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: No more output streams to write to, finishing.
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: [AVIOContext @ 0x7fa7f4c14180] Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=1.31x    
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: video:37kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: Input file #0 (/Users/user11/ffmpeg/input.tif):
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Input stream #0:0 (video): 1 packets read (18100 bytes); 1 frames decoded; 
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Total: 1 packets (18100 bytes) demuxed
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: Output file #0 (/Users/user11/ffmpeg/output.png):
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Output stream #0:0 (video): 1 frames encoded; 1 packets muxed (38013 bytes); 
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output:   Total: 1 packets (38013 bytes) muxed
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: ReencodePicture output: [AVIOContext @ 0x7fa7f4f041c0] Statistics: 18100 bytes read, 0 seeks
May 31, 2021 2:15:51 PM 
INFO: BinaryRepositoryHelper.convertPixTo ffmpeg Process returned : java.lang.UNIXProcess@27ddd392, ended with code 0, and returned in 160 ms, out=/Users/user11/ffmpeg/output.png exists=true
```

**So our questions are:**

1. Is there a way to identify the tiff files that will be converted to png with inverted colors ? So that we can know to which files the 'negate' parameter must be applied.
2. Are there any other FFMPEG parameter that we can use.

This issue has been driving us mad for the last couple of days. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

**Example of Tif picture**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U1a91gTk1gaJb-XAPavNq6UhmjWXZjbM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show the complete log from your first ffmpeg command. Provide a link to one of the TIFF files that has the problem.

Comment: Hi Mounia, please add the commands in a code brackets for a better reading experience. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your intervention. Additional information have been added to the question. If you can help us detect the parameters in charge of converting the colors from the tif to the png, we would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a broken file.

ImageMagick `convert` also does not like the input. [This comment in convert: improper image header #2717](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/2717#issuecomment-708464701) suggests to set the Photometric Interpretation tag with `tiffset`:

```
tiffset -s 262 0 input.tif
```

Now converting with `ffmpeg` should work as expected.